# ANDROID - How do I Remove clicked TableRow from TableLayout

Tags: android, sqlite, tablelayout, tablerow

I am going to remove a TableRow from a TableLayout in android, based on what is clicked. This table layout is populated from SQLiteDatabase. I have tried to set the ID for the clicked row and delete the clicked row. It is worked for only once, when I click the remove button for the second time to delete more row, the application stopped.

I thought this happened because when I remove the second row, which is the ID is 2, the third row which the ID is 3 at first, the row ID becoming 2 when the second row is deleted. 
Any idea how could I remove the selected row from TableLayout??

These are my method for deleting the row :

```
    btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                int rowIDs = tampRowID;
                int SOUDetailNo = tampRowID + LastSOUDetail;

                mytable.removeViewAt(tampRowID);
                b.deleteSOUD(SOUDetailNo); 
                Toast.makeText(Order.this, "SOUploadDetail no "+ Integer.toString(SOUDetailNo) + " has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Toast.makeText(Order.this, "could not parse", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

And I set the row ID in the BuildTable() method :

```
    private void BuildTable() 
             {
                  int rowID = 0;
                  Cursor c = b.readAllSOUD();

                  final int rows = c.getCount();
                  int cols = c.getColumnCount();

                  c.moveToPosition(c.getCount() - 1);

                  // outer for loop
                      final TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                      row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                      row.setClickable(true);
                      rowID++; 
                      row.setId(rowID);
                      row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 

                    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                tampRowID = row.getId();
                        }
                      });


                      // inner for loop
                      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
                      {
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

                        tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        //tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);

                        tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        tv.setTextSize(12);
                        tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
                        tv.setText(c.getString(j));
                        //tv.setBackgroundColor(0x7C5B77);
                        row.addView(tv);
                      }
                      c.moveToNext();
                      mytable.addView(row);  
            }
```

Comment: yes it works also for me with a little costumization.. thank you in advance!!

Comment: sory, my reputation is not enough to upvote ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try at the following answer.

```
public TableLayout mainTableLayout;
private TableRow tableRow;

mainTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTable);
//when you click row item on the table show Menu dialog
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (((TableLayout) v.getParent()).getId() == mainTableLayout
            .getId()) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
    } else {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
    }
    tableRow = (TableRow) v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle() == "Delete") {
        deleteFunction(item.getItemId());
      } else {
        return false;
     }
    return true;
}     


 public void deleteFunction(int id) {
    if (((TableLayout) tableRow.getParent()).equals(mainTableLayout)) {
        mainTableLayout.removeView(tableRow);
        try {
            //what want something to do on the table column eg. for update column. 
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```